# Twilio Flex UI Design

Tags: reactjs, twilio, twilio-flex

I'm creating a contact center using Twilio Flex, I would like to embed a website I already have on Panel 2 so the agent can make some consultations, and make the width of Panel 1 smaller to have a better look at the other panel. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this? What are you having problems with? Can you share your code?

Comment: In the SamplePlugin file I tried to embed the website on CRM container but it's not working --> flex.CRMContainer.defaultProps.uri = "domain.com";

Comment: What's not working? What happens, do you get an error? Can I recommend that you follow the Flex lessons at https://www.twiliotraining.com/ ? There is a lot there that will help what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate CRM or any website into the right panel of the agent website. Follow these steps :

1. Install the Twilio plugin CLI (https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/plugins/cli/install)
2. Run it locally and you will see the agent website in your localhost
3. Configure it as per your requirement
4. Deploy the plugin (https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/plugins/cli/deploy-and-release)
5. Now you will be able to see the changes in your agent website